# Function pointer for inline function C

Tags: c, function-pointers, inline

```
inline void myfunction(){
    //something here
}

void main(){
    void (*p)(void);
    p = myfunction;
    p();
}
```

What kind of machine code different compilers can generate for this, and in what situations?

Comment: Your compiler will certainly make the function non inline but it may also create two verions of the function, one inline and one non inline, all depends on your compiler.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak I only have gcc on my machine and I asked about other compilers too.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak: Testing would only tell you whether the C implementation you use permits it. Since that could be an implementation-specific extension to C, it would not tell you whether it is defined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil how to test whether the function call is `inline`d or not?

Comment: @ajay you can compile with -S flag to generate assembly code.

Answer (score 3):

As your compiler will need the adress of the function, it will generate a stand alone copy of the object code.

Comment: It may also generate inline copies of the function in this source file if the function is used in other places in the file.

Answer (score 2):

***Yes - but it will depend on your compiler and its settings what side effects will occur:***

There are various ways to define inline functions; any given kind of definition might definitely emit stand-alone object code, definitely not emit stand-alone object code, or only emit stand-alone object code if it is known to be needed. Sometimes this can lead to duplication of object code...

***[From Here](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html)***